# NodeJS: Finding a Key that has the most key array matches in a string

Tags: node.js, arrays

I am trying to achieve a small amount of javascript code that is able to locate a key that contains another key with the most array element occurrences in a string. It's a little hard to explain but I have given an example below. I have tried several filters, finds, and lengthy code loops with no luck. Anything would help, thanks :)

```js
const object = {
    keyone: {
        tags: ["game","video","tv","playstation"]
    },
    keytwo: {
        tags: ["book", "sport", "camping", "out"]
    }
};

const string = "This is an example, out playstaion, tv and video games are cool!";

// I am trying to locate the key that contains the most tags in a string.
// In this case the result I am looking for would be "keytwo", 
// because it's tags have greater occurances inside the string (playstaion, tv, video, game/s).
```

Comment: can you provide your attempts?

Comment: @ilkerkaran I have tried using Object.keys(object) and manually checking every single tag with the string then adding the occurances to create a total for each key, however this took too long and I need it to be as fast as possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, though you might want to consider adding [keyword stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

```js
const object = {
    keyone: {
        tags: ["game", "video", "tv", "playstation"]
    },
    keytwo: {
        tags: ["book", "sport", "camping", "out"]
    }
};

const string = "This is an example, out playstaion, tv and video games are cool!";

result = {}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    result[key] = value.tags.reduce((acc, item) => (acc += (string.match(item) || []).length), 0)
}

console.log(result)
```

Result:

```js
{ keyone: 3, keytwo: 1 }
```

Edit:

How to count:

```js
let result_key;
let result_count = 0;

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    const result = value.tags.reduce((acc, item) => (acc += (string.match(item) || []).length), 0);
    if(result > result_count) {
        result_count = result;
        result_key = key;
    }
}

console.log(result_key, result_count)
```

Result:

```js
keyone 3
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I only want it to return a single key name, not just based off a 0 or 1 boolean for multiple objects. :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean re: booleans. 0 and 1 are the occurrences within each.

Comment: I just want to only return the key name, in this case "keytwo". I want to return the key name, that has the most matching "tags" array elements in a string.

Comment: There was a mistake in the original answer, it only counted the last word in the array, see fixed version. There's also another version that counts the highest number. If this is some sort of homework, I strongly suggest you study it closely.